ANTLR4: syntax error: unterminated rule (missing ';')
This is the error I got:
syntax error: unterminated rule (missing ';') detected at 'status_line :' while looking for rule element

The code snippets are below for the related lexers and parsers. How should I fix this?
//parser
status_line
    :   'Chain' chain_name '(' 'policy' policy PKTS 'pkts,' BYTES 'bytes)'
    ;

chain_name
    :   'INPUT' | 'FORWARD' | 'OUTPUT' | CUSTOM_CHAIN
    ;

policy
    :   'ACCEPT' | 'DROP' | 'QUEUE' | 'RETURN'
    ;



//lexer

PKTS
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

BYTES
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

CUSTOM_CHAIN
    :   [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
    ;


I have double checked my tokens and separated 'bytes' ')'.
There was also a general error of: syntax error: mismatched character ':' expecting '{' without indicating what line it was at. Not sure if that will help this resolving this error.

... and what was the input?

antlr4 Iptables.g4 -Dlanguage=Cpp
